# How to write a shell script file that can run a script in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to make a .sh file that when clicked it runs the script inside. I am trying to recursively find a certain string value inside the contents of the files from a given folder, using `$ grep -r "word" /home/folder_name` but I don't know how to do so without running the script in terminal.

Any ideas for this?

Comment: What's the _specific_ problem you're having with your current attempts? How can we see that problem ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Linux shell scripts can be written very basically.To make a shell script, start the script with `#!/bin/sh` and add normal linux commands. That is a simple explanation, but it is sufficient for most simple scenarios.

Example:

`` #!/bin/sh
echo "Hello, World!` ``

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and in particular the first and fourth bullet points within. If you don't know what _specific_ part of the process the OP had a problem with (and exactly what that problem was), you can't know if your answer fixes that problem (and neither can we, so nobody can make an informed decision whether an answer should be upvoted or downvoted).